# Bridging the gap between classical and modern projective geometry

Tags: projective-geometry, book-recommendation

The language of projective geometry is quite common in modern mathematics. For this reason I'd like to learn this subject, however, modern treatments are incredibly abstract. Now, I'm vaguely aware of the history of the subject, so I know that there's much more to it than "let's take an equivalence relation on a vector space over an arbitrary field and formally investigate its properties". I want to fully appreciate the beauty of projective geometry and its connection to traditional geometry.

But so far I've found two kinds of books:

1. Old books which are interesting (except that I've found they rush through notions like cross ratios and fourth harmonics with insufficient motivation), but make no mention of the kinds of ideas I hear about in modern mathematics, like the construction of projective spaces from vector spaces, or the concept of homogeneous coordinates.
2. Modern books which are so abstract that I stop caring half way through page 3 (after the brief historical introduction ended on page 2).

It just seems like a bit of a forgotten field, I can't find that many solid resources. What sort of a roadmap, ideally with book recommendations, can I follow, to get a full picture of the field of projective geometry that will allow me to understand both its roots in classical geometry and how it's used in modern mathematics?

Comment: I like this question. I don't have a deep understanding of projective geometry. But, nonetheless, here are some sources where I feel like you might begin to pick it up: Silverman & Tate's *Rational Points on Elliptic Curves*, appendix; Stillwell's *Four Pillars of Geometry*, chs. 5-6; Reid & Szendroi's *Geometry & Topology*, ch. 5; Arnold's *Real Algebraic Geometry*, ch. 4; Shafarevich's *Basic Algebraic Geometry*, 2nd or 3rd editions, §1. Also entire books: Coxeter's *Projective Geometry* and Richter-Gebert's *Perspectives on Projective Geometry*.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3404841/1257