# Books about synthetic projective geometry

Tags: geometry, reference-request, book-recommendation, projective-geometry, reference-works

Are there books in English about synthetic projective geometry?  More specifically, results of Karl von Staudt  (imaginary elements theory through elliptical involutions, imaginary circle, infinity's imaginary circle)

Answer (score 2):

There's lots to learn from "modern" texts such as Richter-Gebert, Coxeter, et al.  But the heyday of synthetic projective geometry appears to have been in the 19th and early 20th centuries.  After that, both research and pedagogy moved to other topics in math.

For the older texts [archive.org](https://archive.org/) is your friend, going back to Poncelet's groundbreaking [Traité des propriétés projectives des figures](https://archive.org/details/traitdesproprit00goog/page/n7) which introduces *the principle of continuity*, an early view of imaginary elements.

Some examples: [Milne's Cross-Ratio Geometry](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.90533/page/n4) (which makes reference to imaginary elements), and [Pickford's Elementary Projective Geometry](https://archive.org/details/elementaryprojec00pickrich/page/n6).

Dialing in on your interest in imaginary elements, [Chapter XXVII](https://archive.org/details/cu31924059551501/page/n268) of [Russel's Pure Geometry](https://archive.org/details/cu31924059551501/page/n9) discusses imaginary points and lines and gives some practical constructions.

Also check out [Coolidge's Geometry of the Complex Domain](https://archive.org/details/geometryofcomple00cool/page/2) (the final chapter is on Von Staudt Theory) and [Hatton's Theory of the Imaginary in Geometry](https://archive.org/details/cu31924001523665/page/n6).

Answer (score 1):

There is this book by Robin Hartshorne, based on a course he taught at Harvard:

[https://www.amazon.com/Foundations-Projective-Geometry-Robin-Hartshorne/dp/4871878376](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/4871878376)

Answer (score 0):

Derrick Norman Lehmar's book named An Elementary Course Synthetic Projective Geometry is a great book on Synthetic Projective Geometry. I have read it myself and i think it is very informative. Apart from this, can someone tell me where can i get [Detailed Information of Government Exams](https://pendulumedu.com/) as I want to crack UPSC exam.